# How can I view /r and /n if they appear in a column's data?

Tags: sql-server

When I run this select in the Visual Studio database query window:

```
select Kanji from phrase where phrase.English like 'Danc%'
```

I see the Japanese Characters: 踊り り

However the dev that looked at the output of an application that shows the Kanji in a C# debugger is telling me there's a /r and /n somewhere in that string and I would like to be able to check for this in the Visual Studio SQL Query window. Is there a way that I can see the individual characters including the /r and /n in the output of a select? Also how could I retrieve rows from my table where there is a /r and/or a /n that's in the column phrase.kanji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the following replacement when you select:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(Kanji, CHAR(13), '\r'), CHAR(10), '\n')
FROM phrase
WHERE phrase.English LIKE 'Danc%'
```

This would replace carriage return (represented by `CHAR(13)`) with a literal `\r` and it would replace line feed (`CHAR(10)`) by literal `\n`.  Hopefully this would let you see where they are present.

If you wanted to also restrict to only those rows containing either line ending, you could use this:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(Kanji, CHAR(13), '\r'), CHAR(10), '\n')
FROM phrase
WHERE phrase.English LIKE 'Danc%' AND
      (phrase.English LIKE '%'+CHAR(13)+'%' OR phrase.English LIKE '%'+CHAR(10)+'%')
```

Comment: Thanks Tim,  this worked.  Is there also a way that I could select those rows from the table where there's a \r or a \n ? I am not sure how to create the WHERE clause to select them?

Comment: To find the records you can add to your where clause `LIKE '%'+char(10)+'%'` or char(13) as required